# who is responsible for offset maintenance?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Here are the [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)  for `public ConsumerRecords<K,V> poll(long timeout)`

> Fetch data for the topics or partitions specified using one of the
>   subscribe/assign APIs. It is an error to not have subscribed to any
>   topics or partitions before polling for data. On each poll, consumer
>   will try to use the last consumed offset as the starting offset and
>   fetch sequentially. The last consumed offset can be manually set
>   through seek(TopicPartition, long) or automatically set as the last
>   committed offset for the subscribed list of partitions

My question is who(Broker or consumer or zookeper) is responsible for maintaining the offset and where it is stored(memory or disc)? If consumer maintains it in memory, will consumer start reading it from beginning or
consumer application need to persist in disc?

Answer (score 7):

As the "Offsets and Consumer Position" section in the docs you referenced mentions, the offsets are stored by Kafka (the broker):

> Kafka maintains a numerical offset for each record in a partition

Specifically, it stores them in an "internal" consumer offsets topic called "__consumer_offsets".

The "old consumer" api (deprecated in upcoming v0.11) allows you to chose to store offset in kafka or zookeeper.

Additionally, you are free to save offsets on the consumer side and always seek to those offsets at startup, if you so choose.

So, in summary, depending on your consumer api version and your preference, offsets can be stored on the broker or zookeeper and/or on the consumer side.

Comment: Thanks.I read `Offsets and Consumer Position` once more . Does it mean broker also maintains who is consumer along with offset position . The next time consumer polls, broker will see who is the consumer and last offset read and returns the next message . Correct ?

Comment: Second follow up question is on `The old consumer api (deprecated in upcoming v0.11) allows you to chose to store offset in kafka or zookeeper. `  Then who in v0.11 going to maintain the offset and consumer log ?

Comment: v0.11 will deprecate old consumer but not remove it just yet. The preference is to use the new consumer api, which doesn't give zookeeper as an option. Committed offsets are stored in kafka. And yes, Kafka keeps track of last offset per topic per partition per consumer group, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry Michal I am not clear yet. Here are they  Q1) Does it mean broker also maintains who is consumer along with offset position . The next time consumer polls, broker will see who is the consumer and last offset read and returns the next message . Is that correct ? How does kafka uniquely identifies the consumer ? Q2) As you said The old consumer api (deprecated in upcoming v0.11) allows you to chose to store offset in kafka . Who is going to maintain the offset in newer v0.11 ?

Comment: The client library maintains the last read offset in memory and when a client polls the client library gives your app the next messages from its own client side buffer which it continues to fill in the background (if needed) with fetch requests to the brokers. However that mechanism is independent of committed offsets and works even if the app never commits an offset to the _consumer-offsets topic. Committing offsets is like a checkpoint for where you want the app to return should it fail. Poll always returns the next message independent of last committed offset and independent of the broker.

Comment: @HansJespersen Then the statement `Kafka maintains a numerical offset for each record in a partition`, does it mean kafka maintains the committed offset and client maintains the offsets separately in memory ? Also when client crashes and restarted, what is the next offset from it will read the message .Will it use the committed offset then instead of in memory offset?

Comment: If the client crashes and restarts (within 24 hours) then it will restart from the last committed offset. The client can't restart from the last offset in had memory because that memory was lost when it crashed.

Comment: `If the client crashes and restarts (within 24 hours) then it will restart from the last committed offset ` To achieve this first client needs to read the committed offset from broker and send it while retrieve. I believe broker must be storing unique consumer ID for maintaining offset per consumer_id ?

Comment: @HansJespersen Can you please reply to my last comment ?

Comment: Yes the Kafka consumer library (client) first needs to read the last committed offset which it can retrieve from the broker where it is stored in the _consumer-offsets topic. Offsets are stored based on unique consumer group ID as well as topic name and partition number. If there are more than 1 consumers in the group then any one of them might pickup at the last committed offset.